# wpa_cli action script example

Tags: documentation, wpa-cli

I have been googling since morning about any wpa_cli actionscript example and the commands but can't any decent one. can someone help me with some info or link please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from [arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wpa_supplicant#wpa_cli_action_script):

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$2" in
    CONNECTED)
        notify-send "WPA supplicant: connection established";
        ;;
    DISCONNECTED)
        notify-send "WPA supplicant: connection lost";
        ;;
esac
```

> Remember to make the script executable, then use the `-a` flag to pass the script path to `wpa_cli`:

> ```
> $ wpa_cli -a /path/to/script
> ```

Comment: How i can use wpa_cli to change from network to another by network SSID?